# where my datas store if i use sharedpreference in android

Tags: android

> i learned about Sharedpreferences in android to save user name and password thats works well, please refer my code below,

```
SavePreferences("MEM1", "two");
SavePreferences("MEM2", "one");
SavePreferences("MEM3", "three");
SavePreferences("MEM3", "four");
LoadPreferences();
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

   private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");       
   }
```

> my doubt is where my given datas are stored if i use Sharedpreferences.Actually what happens if i use Sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared preference will be stored in internal memory of the devices inside the package folder which will be located at /data/data/your.package.name/shared_prefs.

You can try yourself and see the list of all the preferences stored there using ls command in shell or file explorer in adt.

All those are stored in a xml format.

For your example there will be a shared preference stored at  /data/data/your.package.name/shared_prefs/MY_SHARED_PREF.xml.

**TIP**
When storing password you should always encrypt the password before storing. Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html) article

Comment: @ vivek:is the datas are stored permenently as xml format suppose we switched off and then switched on our mobile.why i asking is, on first time i saved the details and then i comment (//SavePreferences("MEM1", "two");) saved lines . then i close my emulator and debug in new emulator . now it show the value as ""(empty) only

Comment: The stored preferences are almost permanent as long as you clear the cache for the app. In your case, i am not sure but you will be starting the emulator with wipe user data checked. This will result in clearing the cache for all the apps.

Comment: Thank u very much for worthful details. how to see the questions if anybody ask questions like me.....